# PHP mysql how to check if given datetime is not exist in database?

Tags: php, mysql

My database store booking datetime. When a new user want to book at new datetime, I want to popup a message "sorry not allow book at this time" if his new booking time is conflict to previous booking datetime in database.

Example, hour in 24 hours format :
oldBook 14 - 16
oldBook 22 - 01 (nextday)

newBook 15 - 17 (Fail)
newBook 13 - 17 (Fail)
newBook 15 - 16 (Fail)
newBook 12 - 14 (Allow)
newBook 17 - 19 (Allow)
newBook 00 - 02 (Fail) (nextday)

Codes :

```
<?php
foreach ($oldBooks As $oldBook)
{
    $oldBookStart = $oldBook['startDateTime']; //format is YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    $oldBookEnd = $oldBook['endDateTime'];
    $newBookStart = "2020-10-19 15:00:00";
    $newBookEnd = "2020-10-19 17:00:00";
    checkAvailablity($newBookStart,$newBookEnd,$oldBookStart,$oldBookEnd);
}

function checkAvailablity($newBookStart,$newBookEnd,$oldBookStart,$oldBookEnd)
{
    if(($newBookStart > $oldBookStart && $newBookEnd < $oldBookEnd) || 
       ($newBookStart < $oldBookStart && $newBookEnd > $oldBookEnd)) //Problem is here
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry not able to book at this time')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

In function checkAvailablity(), do I really need to write many if OR statements for all posible comparison between newBook and oldBook? any easier way to acheive it? Maybe do like if value is exist in array?

Comment: That's not a particularly complicated `if` statement. Those are the necessary calculations to do what you need. It's not clear why you feel this is an issue, to be honest.

Comment: There will be more than 6 OR statements... I thought it is bad coding style make things messy.

Comment: Why would there be more than 6 ORs? You haven't shown any in the example. It's not clear what other calculations you think you need in order to calculate a date overlap. Please explain where you think these ORs would go and what they would look like. Have you got a specific problem with the code above which you can tell us about? Does it not produce the expected result?

Comment: If you store this in a DB, then you can do the check directly in a query (means you don't have to do it in PHP). That said, if you do it in PHP, you don't do all checks in one go - you iterate over the times that are occupied, and compare against the new time. If there's a conflic with 1 or more, throw an exception or handle it in some other way.

Comment: Qirel, how to query check if the time and date exist in database? Is it I need to have many OR statements at WHERE clause?

Comment: @ADyson, need to have many OR statement because `newBook 15 - 17 (Fail)
newBook 13 - 17 (Fail)
newBook 15 - 16 (Fail)
newBook 12 - 14 (Allow)
newBook 17 - 19 (Allow)`

Comment: Where would the OR be? It still makes no sense to say you want that. Just make an array of newBook values and loop through them, as you do with the oldBook

Comment: @ADyson When u compare `oldBook 14 - 16` with `newBook 15 - 16`, I need to write another OR statement if OldBookEnd == newBookEnd. When compare for `newBook 12 - 14 (Allow)` then need another OR, when comparing for `newBook 17 - 19 (Allow)` then need another OR. Too many OR statement might miss out some possible condition... I am looking for better way like "exist_in" rather than comparing if OR to avoid possible miss.

Comment: No you don't need that. As we keep saying, compare each set separately. Use a loop to go through all the comparisons in one by one.  keep a list of the results. That's the alternative